Having trouble with Queuable job calling batch process
This thread describes how the process should work, but I'm seeing an error when I try to call the batch job:

Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void DeliveryScheduleSync_batch() from the type DeliveryScheduleSync

Here is the code from the Queueable:
public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
    Boolean isRunning = Utils.deliveryScheduleProcessing;
    if(!isRunning && myContext.triggerType == 'Delivery_Schedule__c' && myContext.isAfter){
        
        isRunning = true;
        Database.executeBatch(DeliveryScheduleSync_batch());
    }
}

And here is the batch:
global DeliveryScheduleSync_batch(){
    global void createQueryString() { 
        // Retrieve any Delivery Schedules that have changed recently
        //  that are either Master Schedules or linked to one
        Id masterScheduleRTId = Utils.getRecordTypeId('Delivery_Schedule__c', 'Master Schedule');
        
        Date yesterday = System.today().addDays(-1);
        query = 'SELECT Id, RecordTypeId, AssetId__c, Contact__c ' + 
                'FROM   Delivery_Schedule__c ' +
                'WHERE  LastModifiedDate > :' + yesterday + 
                'AND    RecordTypeId == ' + masterScheduleRTId + 
                'OR     Master_Schedule__c <> null';
    }
        
    global Database.Querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        createQueryString();        
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Delivery_Schedule__c> oDeliverySchedules){
     ....


You need to pass into Database.executeBatch() an instance of your class that implements the Batchable interface.
Database.executeBatch(DeliveryScheduleSync_batch());
should be
Database.executeBatch(new DeliveryScheduleSync_batch());

Also, side note: Probably a good idea to make your batch class use the public modifier for itself (and its methods) instead of global so you don't pollute the global namespace (unless you're making a managed package).

Thank you Derek! All good (and yes, I updated the modifiers to Public).
